# Why can't I undo my delete vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

I chose to delete a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073841/why-does-i1-do-increment-while-i-does-not) and now I can't undo the delete,

I can delete (have a option) again although it seems irrelevant

Is this behavior of unable to undo delete vote is by design?

Why should I vote delete more than once? According to delete tool tip message it count 2 more votes from other users only to delete question entirely

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes

Comment: @SamuelLiew what happens if I vote to delete more than once?

Comment: I guess you can call it "by design", but it's more of a "not yet implemented" thing.

Comment: @Stijn Why should I vote delete more than once? According to tooltip message it should count 2 more votes from other users only

Comment: I think you just get an error message saying you've already voted to delete.

Comment: @Stijn true. so it just a missing implementation of undo vote

Comment: Well, just tested: you can't retract an **Undelete** vote either.